# Как вызвать функцию из одного класса находясь в другом?

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне надо что бы из класса `Input`, при правильном вводе и нажатии кнопки, вызвалась функция `output_res`  которая находится в классе `Output`, я новичок так что будьте готовы к говнокоду)

файл `gui`:

```
from tkinter import *
from calculation import *


class Output(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, output_res=None):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.res = output_res
        self.out()
        
        
    def out(self):
        self.OFFSET_X = 60
        self.OFFSET_Y = 50

        self.canv = Canvas(self, bg="white", width=700, height=700)
        self.canv.pack()


    def output_res(self, res, prob):
        DIMEN_COORDPL = 500 # dimension of the coordinate plane
        OFFSET_X = self.OFFSET_X
        OFFSET_Y = self.OFFSET_Y
        STEP_X = DIMEN_COORDPL / 32 # 32 is number of cards

        self.canv.create_text(OFFSET_X, DIMEN_COORDPL + OFFSET_Y + 50, text = res)

        self.canv.create_line(OFFSET_X, OFFSET_Y,
                             OFFSET_X,OFFSET_Y + DIMEN_COORDPL, width=2) 
        self.canv.create_line(OFFSET_X, OFFSET_Y + DIMEN_COORDPL,
                             OFFSET_X + DIMEN_COORDPL + STEP_X, OFFSET_Y + DIMEN_COORDPL, width=2)
        
        MAXVALUE_Y = max(prob.values())
        #y / Y * DIMEN_COORDPL
        #x * STEP_X
        iter = tuple(prob)
        for i in iter:
            term_value = prob[i] / MAXVALUE_Y * DIMEN_COORDPL # hight 
            prob.update({i:term_value})
        iter = iter[:len(iter) - 1]


        self.canv.create_text(OFFSET_X - 20, OFFSET_Y, text="%0.3f" % (MAXVALUE_Y))
        self.canv.create_text(OFFSET_X - 20, OFFSET_Y + DIMEN_COORDPL / 2, text="%0.3f" % (MAXVALUE_Y / 2))

        for i in iter:
            self.canv.create_text(OFFSET_X + (i-1) * STEP_X,
                                DIMEN_COORDPL + OFFSET_Y + 15,
                                text = str(i))

            self.canv.create_line(OFFSET_X + (i-1) * STEP_X,
                                DIMEN_COORDPL + OFFSET_Y - prob[i],
                                OFFSET_X + (i) * STEP_X,
                                DIMEN_COORDPL + OFFSET_Y - prob[i + 1],
                                width=2.5, fill="red")
        else:
            self.canv.create_text(OFFSET_X + (33) * STEP_X,
                                DIMEN_COORDPL + OFFSET_Y + 15,
                                text = str(34))

        

class Input(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.output_res = None
        self.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.input_num_exp()

    def input_num_exp(self):
        self.entry = Entry(self, bg="red")
        self.bat = Button(self, text = "ok", width=4, relief = FLAT)
        self.bat.bind('<Button-1>', self.click)


        self.bat.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def click(self, _):
            try:
                num = int(self.entry.get())
                if num <= 0:
                    raise ValueError
                res, prob = calculation(num)
                # вызов функции output_res с аргументами res, prob
                
            except ValueError:
                pass

    
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('700x850+10+10')
    root.minsize(700, 700)
    root.maxsize(850, 850)
    inp = Input(root)
    out = Output(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

файл `calculation` (можете на него не обращать внимания он просто возвращает строку и число):

```
from gui import *
from math import sqrt
from numpy import zeros, ones, hstack, random, nonzero 


def probability(x, num_exp):
    for i in x:
        x[i] /= num_exp
    return x

def calculation(num_exp):
    
    expected_math = 0
    expected_mathematical_pow2 = 0
    x = {i:0 for i in range(1, 35)}

    a = ones(4, int) 
    b = zeros(32, int)
    place_tuze = hstack([a,b])

    for i in range(num_exp):
        random.shuffle(place_tuze)
        term = nonzero(place_tuze == 1)[0][0] + 1

        expected_math += term
        expected_mathematical_pow2 += term ** 2
        x[term] += 1

    expected_math /= num_exp
    expected_mathematical_pow2 /= num_exp
    
    prob = probability(x, num_exp)

    res = ("M[x] = \t" + "%0.6f" % (expected_math) + "\n")
    disp = expected_mathematical_pow2 - expected_math ** 2
    res += ("D[x] = \t" + "%0.6f" % (disp) + "\n")
    res += ("σ = \t" + "%0.6f" % (sqrt(disp)))

    return res, prob
```

Answer (score 0):

Постараюсь привести базовый пример отвечающий на Ваш вопрос. Подставить его в код думаю будет не сложно.

```py
class A: # из которого надо вызываеть функцию (метод)
    def fun_A(self): 
        print("Hello World!")

    @staticmethod
    def fun_A2():
        print("Статический метод")

class B:
    def fun_B(self):
        a = A() # Создаем экземпляр класса A
        a.fun_A() # Вызываем функцию из класса A
        # или... 
        A.fun_A2() # Используем статический метод.. 

b = B()
b.fun_B()
```